# Como alterar atributos de componentes entre Forms?

Tags: c#

Tenho uma aplicação em C# com um Form pai (FRM_PRINCIPAL) que contém um botão (BTN_ACT) que chama um Form filho (Form2), que por sua vez contém um botão (BTN_REG) contendo algumas funções, entre elas uma seria tornar o BTN_ACT em invisível (BTN_ACT.Visible=False;). Como eu faria isso?
Simplificando: Basicamente tornar o botão do primeiro Form em invisível através do botão de um segundo Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu FRM_PRINCIPAL, você precisa criar um método público para definir a visibilidade do seu botão.

```
public void AlteraVisibilidadeBtnAct(bool visivel)
{
    this.BTN_ACT.Visible = visivel;
}
```

No método click do seu botão BTN_REG, você chama o método criado acima da seguinte forma, se o Form2 for filho do seu FRM_PRINCIPAL. Um form é filho do outro quando a propriedade MdiParent é definida para o filho.

```
private void BTN_REG_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ParentForm.AlteraVisibilidadeBtnAct(false);
}
```

Se o Form2 não for filho do FRM_PRINCIPAL, você deve adicionar o FRM_PRINCIPAL no construtor do Form2, para depois acessá-lo no evento click.

```
private FRM_PRINCIPAL frmPrincipal;

public Form2(FRM_PRINCIPAL frmPrincipal)
{
    this.frmPrincipal = frmPrincipal;
}

private void BTN_REG_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    frmPrincipal.AlteraVisibilidadeBtnAct(false);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Bernardo! O código que estou compilando que aparentemente se encaixa em meu caso é o que você disse "Se o Form2 não for filho do FRM_PRINCIPAL...". Porém estou recebendo "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in...". Este erro está acontecendo na linha frmPrincipal.AlteraVisibilidadeBtnAct(false); no meu Form2.

Comment: Você precisa passar como parâmetro o FRM_PRINCIPAL para o Form2, na linha onde o Form2 é criado. O código ficaria algo assim: Form2 form2 = new Form2(this), se você estiver criando o Form2 dentro da classe FRM_PRINCIPAL.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!